# Data Extraction in Python

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, named-entity-extraction

I've been given a data set consisting of three columns. One column has transaction information, one has a store number, and one has sections. My goal is to extract the store number from the transaction information column for 300 different stores using entity extraction. My thought process behind this was to make something similar to how companies search resumes for key words using a word bank, since I have the store numbers in a separate column already. I have the .csv file read into my program, and I have the store numbers stored into their own array. I'm trying to figure out how to search the transaction information column for those store numbers.

Code so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

file = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\cspea\Desktop\assignment.csv')
print(file)

store_number_array = file['store_number'].to_numpy()
print(store_number_array)
```

Sample data set (in .csv format):

```
transaction_descriptor,store_number,dataset
DOLRTREE 2257 00022574 ROSWELL,2257,train
AUTOZONE #3547,3547,train
TGI FRIDAYS 1485 0000,1485,train
BUFFALO WILD WINGS 003,3,train
J. CREW #568 0,568,train
```

Any tips would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for your time and assistance in advance :)

Comment: so you want to get the store_number which is inside transaction_descriptor right ?

Comment: @DataSciRookie exactly

Comment: I guess there is not a specific order each time in term of position ?

Comment: @DataSciRookie not really. in the file, the stores and their store numbers are always next to each other. I'm just trying to figure out how to get the store numbers out of the transaction_descriptors

Comment: I was going to try to use the store_number 'column' as a word bank to search for the store numbers in the transaction_descriptor. Is there an easier way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this :

```
df['c'] = df['transaction_descriptor'].apply(lambda x: (df[df['transaction_descriptor'].str.contains(x)]['store_number']))[0]
for index,row in df.loc[df['c'].isna(),:].iterrows():
    test_=df.loc[index,'store_number']
    test=df.loc[index,'transaction_descriptor']
    result=[s for s in test.split() if str(test_) in s]
    
    df.loc[index,'c']=result
```

Comment: When I run it and print the result, I get 1485. Is there a way to loop this over every one of the transaction_descriptors?

Comment: Also, there are a few stores that have a number that starts with a letter, like
MCDONALD'S F1013,F1013,train
What would I do then?

Comment: do you need the letter also ?

Comment: Yeah. If it was all digits, it would be a hell of a lot easier lol

Comment: Also, when I tried the J. CREW #568 0, 568, train one, it just returned [0], I'm assuming because of the #. Is there a way around that?

Comment: do you always have store_number ?

Comment: Yeah. There's a total of 300 different stores, each has a unique store number. The first column has the transaction_descriptor, the second column has the store number in regards to the store. So I always have the store number on its own as well as somewhere in the transaction_descriptor

Comment: @ConradSpeak I edited my answer can you try it please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244594/discussion-between-conrad-speak-and-datascirookie).